Made a string capitalizer in c and it breaks if it encounters a space
The title basically sums it up. I first compared if the characters of the string are in between a and z. then, if they are, reduced their ascii by 32, hence obtaining their capitals.
But if the function encounters a space in the string, it modifies the argument string such that all the rest after the space are not capitalized and added back in the string.
Eg the desired output was WANNA GO but it outputs WANNA.
#include <stdio.h>

void capitalizer(char arr[]){
     for(int i=0; arr[i]!='\0'; i++)
     {
          if('a' < arr[i] < 'z'){
               arr[i] -= 32; 
          }
     }
}

int main() {
    char name[] = "wanna go";
    puts(name);
    capitalizer(name);
    puts(name);

    return 0;
}

i changed the comparing condition to if('a' <= arr[i] && arr[i] <= 'z') and it worked so i guess thats where the issue is.

I’m voting to close this question because there is no more question.

hmmm.... well, you have found the bug so what is the question? Are you asking why the first attempt didn't work?

duplicate: Is (val1 > val2 > val3) a valid comparison in C? No, it's parsed as (val1 > val2) > val3. Why do most mainstream languages not support x < y < z syntax for 3-way Boolean comparisons?, Why does (0 < 5 < 2) result true?

Use toupper()


first compared if the characters of the string are in between a and z.

'a' < arr[i] < 'z' does not do that.
'a' < arr[i] < 'z' is like ('a' < arr[i]) < 'z'.
('a' < arr[i]) will have the value of 0 or 1 (false or true).  Then 0 or 1 is compared to 'z', which for ASCII is always true.
Consequently your code is equivalent to:
void capitalizer(char arr[]){
     for(int i=0; arr[i]!='\0'; i++)
     {
         arr[i] -= 32; 
     }
}

So you subtract 32 from all characters of the input.
Since a space has the ascii value 32, the result will be zero. Zero is the string termination character. That explains why your result ends up as a string truncated at the first space in the input string.
If you want to test if a character is between a ans z you should do:
`if('a' <= arr[i] && arr[i] <= 'z')`

However, you shouldn't write your own code for doing such a check. C already have the function islower. That said, you shouldn't even do the conversion to upper case with your own code as C already have the function toupper
